# Installing Laravel on centos

Tags: php, laravel, centos

I have installed Centos 7 and I want to install Laravel 5 on it,
I already installed PHP, MySQL and Apache also I installed composer and created a new Laravel project but when I try to access it's index file that is in public folder of the project I get this error :

```
Remote server or file not found
You tried to access the address http://localhost/ToDo/public/, which is currently   unavailable.
```

other PHP files in `/var/www/html` folder work great

Comment: Show us the Apache virtual host that is supposed to serve the Laravel app.

Comment: @Kaloyan Doichinov sorry but i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solved it:
i disabled SELinux and changed the readonly access to read and write access for my project folder with this command: chmod -R 757 folder